# Wordpress translation with language files

Tags: php, wordpress, translation, wpml, poedit

I have 2 examples, 1 work and the other not.

I'm fixing a plugin and I have some issue with the translation using the language file.

Some place I have this code:

```
<label><?php echo __('Select Location', 'abc-manager'); ?></label>
```

This code work and it translate "Select Location" to "Selectionner le lieu" when the website is in french.

But I have a button like that:

```
return apply_filters( 'abc-details_button', __('View detail', 'abc-manager') );
```

And I have the (View detail) translatate in my language file like the first example but I dont find the way to make "View detail" to show "Voir les details" in my button in french?

Any idea for a solution?